# GTK+ menu item not sensitizing first call to gtk_widget_set_sensitive()

Tags: menu, gtk

My application has an "Actions" menu with a "Delete" submenu which does not get sensitized the first time I select an item from a list, even though I am explicitly calling

gtk_widget_set_sensitive(GTK_WIDGET(DeleteMenuItem), TRUE);

in the button release event of the treeview for the list.

However... If I select an item from the list, select the "Actions" menu, then select *another* item from the list, then select "Actions" menu item, the "Delete" menu item is now sensitized.

Is this a bug in GTK? (version 2.4.6, I know, but unfortunately, I am not able to go to a newer version of the GTK)

I appreciate the help,
bernie

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "button release event" is not triggered, maybe because there is not "release event" the first time.  You might want to use a different event (I could not get clearly the use case, so I am not suggesting any event in particular).

In short: gtk_widget_set_sensitive() is not the problem, the problem is *when* you call it.